# Could not find a configuration file for package "ECM" that is compatible with requested version 1.5.0

Tags: linux, terminal, kde, build, cmake

I tried to download "ECMConfig.cmake" from repository, but terminal gives me an error: **"*question's title* + The following configuration files were considered but not accepted: ECMConfig.cmake : version is unknowed.**
I tried to search on Google, but got nothing. I wanted to compile from source "kde frameworks" using this command:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/john/QtProjects/KDEStuff/frameworkintegration/build/ 
         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debugfull -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/john/Downloads/
```

P.S:
"/home/john/Downloads/" - where my *.cmake is.

Comment: Just in case remember it could also happen when not having read access on `/usr/share`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try to clone, compile and install the `extra-cmake-modules` KDE project.

```
git clone https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/extra-cmake-modules.git 
cd extra-cmake-modules
mkdir build && cd build    
cmake ..
make && sudo make install
```

Comment: Too bad that these commands did not work in my case. I've got `CMake Error at /usr/local/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQmake.cmake:23` with message `QMake call failed: No such file or directory` even after execution of all above. Update is appreciated.

Comment: @im_infamous Please check that last command `sudo make install` was succesfull.

Comment: Package is now located @ https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules

Comment: The GitHub link is a mirror available for everyone's convenience. The main git repository is now at: https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/extra-cmake-modules.git

Comment: thanks lot, https://github.com/Tatsh/kate-wakatime/issues/16

Answer (score 41):

In my case I simply had to install the *extra-cmake-modules* package.

```sh
sudo pacman -S extra-cmake-modules
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: Worked for me with Fedora 30.

Comment: Or 
sudo apt-get install extra-cmake-modules

Comment: Worked for me with Debian 10.

Comment: Worked on Manjaro